# Spring how to reuse specification on a relationship

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

For simplicity, assume we have a customers table and an order table. A customer can have multiple orders.

Now I created a `isBirthday` specification for the customers birthday. Using it will give me all customers celebrating their birthday today `customerRepository.findAll(hasBirthday());`

Now I want to reuse this specification on the ordersReposity.

```
ordersRepository.findAll(hasBirthday(), someOrderSpecifiation1(), someOrderSpecifiation2(), ...);
```

I don't want to rewrite the same `hasBirthday` specification but now with a join on customers for the orders table.

Of course, I can do something like this:

`customerRepository.findAll(hasBirthday()).stream().filter(//somelogic);` But this wouldn't be ideal with more complex logic.

Is there I way I can reuse the specification?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA's specifications are just simple classes providing a `Predicate` as a result of a method call.

You can use the normal ways of OOP to reuse code with them.

I recommend the normal way of extracting duplicated code with a code base:

Write both implementations with generous use of cut and paste, until they both work. Without doubt your tests will tell you when you reached that point.

Then take a look at the code you got an how to extract the common parts.
A template pattern might be useful, where you extract the code that actually gives you the customer reference on which you apply the actual predicate.